# Easy way to refactor table and column names in a Linq .DBML file?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I've recently made a large series of changes to the names of columns and tables within our database (SQL Server).  Now I need to update the Linq to SQL Model (.DBML) file to reflect this.

In the past when I've done this; I usually manually rename the column / table then have to go through all instances in the code and rename accordingly.  However this is pretty cumbersome as you can imagine.

Is there an easier way to refactor names in .DBML, something along the lines of 
"Right Click -> Refactor -> Rename" but for a .DBML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the reason I chose not to use the dbml way to implement LINQ 2 SQL in my project. I instead defined the classes myself and mapped to tables and columns using attributes.. I know its a lot work. but its worth it..

**An example:**

```
    [Table(Name = "Transaction")]
    public partial class Transaction
    {
        private decimal _amount;   
        private int _id
        private DateTime _payDate;
        private int _currencyId;

        private EntityRef<Currency> _currencyMaster;

        partial void OnLoaded();
        partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
        partial void OnCreated();        

        public Transaction()
        {            
            _currencyMaster = default(EntityRef<Currency>);
            OnCreated();
        }

       [Column(Storage = "_id", AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return _id;
            }
            protected set
            {
                if ((_id != value))
                {
                    OnPropertyChanging();
                    _id = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_amount", DbType = "Decimal(18,2) NOT NULL", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
        public decimal Amount
        {
            get
            {
                return _amount;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((_amount != value))
                {
                    OnPropertyChanging();
                    _amount = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Amount");
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_currencyId", DbType = "INT NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
        public int CurrencyId
        {
            get
            {
                return _currencyId;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((_currencyId != value))
                {
                    OnPropertyChanging();
                    _currencyId = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrencyId");
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_payDate", DbType = "DateTime NOT NULL", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
        public DateTime PayDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _payDate;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((_payDate != value))
                {
                    OnPropertyChanging();
                    _payDate = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PayDate");
                }
            }
        }

        [Association(Name = "Transaction_Currency", Storage = "_currencyMaster", ThisKey = "CurrencyId", OtherKey = "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
        public Currency Currency
        {
            get
            {
                return _currencyMaster.Entity;
            }
            set
            {
                Currency previousValue = _currencyMaster.Entity;
                if (((previousValue != value)
                            || (_currencyMaster.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
                {
                    OnPropertyChanging();
                    if ((previousValue != null))
                    {
                        _currencyMaster.Entity = null;
                        previousValue.Transactions.Remove(this);
                    }
                    _currencyMaster.Entity = value;
                    if ((value != null))
                    {
                        value.Transactions.Add(this);
                        _currencyId = value.Id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _currencyId = default(int);
                    }
                    OnPropertyChanged("Currency");
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That there is no "refresh" button for DBML.  I typically remove everything, and then drag the views & procedures back from Server Explorer.  Be sure to save the DBML after cleaning it, otherwise it will keep the old definitions.

Comment: Will this affect any partial classes added to the original objects?

Comment: @Click-Rex: I don't think so, you always have to edit those by hand.

Comment: This is inexcusable. Even if there were a refresh button, that would still be horribly inadequate. Every time you build the solution, it should give you an error if your LINQ queries don't match the schema. As it stands, if you rename something, you won't find out until run time that there is a problem, even though VS has all the information it needs to stop such a problem at build time. It's really upsetting.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Huagati DBML Tools for this very purpose, and found it to work very well.

Check it out, it's pretty cheap for a single developer license.

[Huagati DBML Tools](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/)